# Using setters and getters and improving code

Tags: java

i have fixed my java code about computing a declared and inputted variable..

```
public class JavaApplication1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    static double maxLoad = 500;
    static double currLoad;
    static double loadInput = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String cpNumber;

        System.out.print("Enter Cellphone Number: ");
        cpNumber = sc.nextLine();
//        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Enter load to be bought: ");
        loadInput = sc.nextDouble();

        currLoad = computeLoad(maxLoad, loadInput);
        System.out.println(loadInput + " was loaded to " + cpNumber);
        System.out.println("Current Load Wallet is now only : " + currLoad);
    }

    public static double computeLoad(double x, double y) {
        return x - y;
    }
}
```

i just wanted to ask for opinions from pros on how to improve my code writing and how to add a setter getter method to it like some validations like returning something when the inputted value is not correct.

Comment: First of all, move away from `static` members as much as possible.

Comment: You might be better served going to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). HTH

Comment: The stack overflow is not place for this kind of question please go to code review.

Comment: thanks for that, but i also wanted to know how to add the setter getter method for this simple code.

Comment: What setter getter method? You don't have an object, whats the point of that?

Comment: Code improvement suggestion: indent your code properly and use whitespace appropriately.

Comment: @JoeC My professor asked me to make one for this... i think for the currLoad and cpNumber variable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, let's analyse the pros of your code.

- Your methods are appropriately named
- Your variables conform to the Java Naming Convention
- Your naming gives an indication of the purpose of a variable *(in most cases)*.

And the cons.

- You're misusing static.
- You've not got any comments
- You've not declared a constant (`maxLoad`) as a `final` variable.
- Your class name gives no indication to the purpose of the class, whatsoever.
- You've left your class members exposed. These should be private, and if the user needs to know about them then there should be some `getters` and `setters` to retrieve them.
- You've got parameter `x` and parameter `y` in your `computeLoad` method. What are `x` and `y`? This is obscure naming, and you should avoid `x` and `y` at all costs (unless of course you're using co-ordinates).

So after some consideration, I applied this kind of thinking to your code and made the following changes:

```
public class Wallet { 

    // The scanner used to read input data.
    private Scanner sc;
    // The maximum load allowed in the wallet.
    private final double MAX_LOAD = 500;
    // The current load in the wallet.
    private double currLoad;
    // The current input from the user.
    private double loadInput;

    /** This is the constructor. **/
    public JavaApplication1() {
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        currLoad = 0.0;
        loadInput = 0.0; 
        readInput();
   }

   /** 
    * Reads input from the user.
    *
    */
   public void readInput() {
        System.out.print("Enter Cellphone Number: ");
        cpNumber = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter load to be bought: ");
        loadInput = sc.nextDouble();

        // Perform calculation using input.
        currLoad = computeLoad(maxLoad, loadInput);
        System.out.println(loadInput + " was loaded to " + cpNumber);
        System.out.println("Current Load Wallet is now only : " + currLoad);
   }

   /** 
    * Performs computation on the input.
    * @param maxLoad the first value.
    * @param loadInput the second value.
    **/
   private double computeLoad(double maxLoad, double loadInput) {
       return maxLoad - loadInput;
   }

   /** The main thread. Used to create a new instance of JavaApplication1.
    * 
    *  This is so we don't need to litter static all over the place.
    */
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       new Wallet();
   }

}
```

**Getters and Setters**

With your shiny new, improved code, maybe it's time to add some getters and setters. These have an extremely clear naming convention that you *100%* must follow. I'll give you an example. Let's say you want to write a getter for your `currLoad` value. Then it will look like this:

```
/**
 *  Returns the current load.
 *  @return the current wallet load.
 */
public double getCurrLoad()
{
    return currLoad;
}
```

See how it is pre-pended with `get`, and all subsequent words start with a capital letter? The next one is the setter.

```
/**
 * Updates the value in currLoad. Sets a new current wallet load.
 *
 * @param currLoad the new current wallet load.
 */
public void setCurrLoad(double currLoad)
{
    this.currLoad = currLoad;
}
```

Comment: wow man! thanks for that! btw, why did you transfer the codes inside the main to a new method? just curious.. is it the right thing to do?

Comment: Well, while the code is inside your main thread, it is in a `static` context. While it is in a `static` context, it can only access other values that are in a `static` context. So I moved the code into an instance method, and if you look inside the constructor, it calls `readInput` from the constructor. This is from the `instance` context, and it means you don't need to label all of your fields as `static`.

Comment: You have to many comments. What is the point of having something like this `// The load input. private double loadInput;` ?

Comment: I'm trying to illustrate the point to OP that you need to comment your fields. I'll edit the comment to make it more useful.

Comment: thanks for the setter and getter, can i add a validation inside the setter/getter method now? like if(cpNumber == "" || cpNumber == null){ System.out.println("CP Number is Null");}

Comment: Yeah definitely! But I wouldn't go comparing a `double` with `null`. `double` is a primitive type, so it will *always* have a value. You could check if `cpNumber == 0`, if you wanted a non-zero value. Also, if this answer helped you the most, could you please mark it as correct.

Comment: cpNumber is a string but i get what you mean :) i would definitely mark this as the solution for it really helped me a lot good sir!

Comment: @Chris, IMHO you do not need to comment the field, instead you just can call it `currentLoad` and create a class `wallet`

Comment: @Chris where should i put the setter getter method?

Comment: Well the setter and getter methods should go inside the class that they are `setting` and `getting` the values of :P @Vash Sorry, I forgot to make that change, however I did specify it as an issue in the list. I'll change it now.

Answer (score 4):

When having an application built inside a single (main) class, having getters and setters does not make much sense. Getters and setters make sense when you're trying to apply **encapsulation** on some classes, applying the **Java beans** principles. Try looking up the highlighted keywords.

A main class is not quite an encapsulation-ready class. It is rather an entry point to Java code execution. If your application gets more complex, you'll end up by manipulating more objects of different classes. Then it would make sense to define getters and setters.

Moreover, getters and setters are used to expose instance fields, not static variables.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class JavaApplication1 {`
```

This should mean something, determine the purpose of class.

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

You have moved the comment of method main and assigned to `sc` member

```
static double maxLoad = 500;
static double currLoad;
static double loadInput = 0;
```

You allocate the fields that are not necessarily class members

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

You have implemented your logic in main method that is responsible for application initialization and run

```
String cpNumber;
```

You have declared filed that name is ambiguous

```
System.out.print("Enter Cellphone Number: ");
cpNumber = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println();
```

You have left a unnecessary comment that is dead code.

```
currLoad = computeLoad(maxLoad, loadInput);
```

You use a field that was declared earlier, it should be declared here.

```
System.out.println(loadInput + " was loaded to " + cpNumber);
System.out.println("Current Load Wallet is now only : " + currLoad);
```

You should use formats for string.

---

For the first code is not so bad. But there is a place for improvement.

Lest apply some simple rules.

- Use clear names
- Declare variable when required
- Use comments to explain complex parts of code

---

Example:

```
public class MyFirstProgram {

    private static double MAXIMUM_LOAD = 500.0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // We will read from the console. 

        System.out.print("Enter Cellphone Number: ");

        String cellPhoneNumber = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter load to be bought: ");
        double inputLoad = sc.nextDouble();

        double computedLoad = computeLoad(maxLoad, loadInput);


        System.out.println("%1$.2f was loaded to %s", inputLoad, cellPhoneNumber); 
        System.out.println("Current Load Wallet is now only : %1$.2f" computedLoad );
    }

    public static double computeLoad(double x, double y) {
        return x - y;
    }
}
```

---

From this we can improve even more but guide for you. Try to use those tree rules to create readable code.

The next step is to separate the structure from controller.

---

Our structure:

```
public class Load {

    private final String cellPhoneNumber;
    private double load; 

    public Load(String cellPhoneNUmber) {
        this.cellPhoneNumber = cellPhoneNumber
    }

    public void setLoad(double load) {
        this.load = load;
    }

    public doulbe getLoad() {
        return this.load;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%1$.2f is loaded to %s", getLoad(), cellPhoneNumber);
    }
}
```

---

our logic:

```
 public class MyFirstProgram {

     private static double MAXIMUM_LOAD = 500.0;

     public static void main(String[] args) {

         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); //We will read from the console. 

         System.out.print("Enter Cellphone Number: ");
         Load load = new Load(sc.nextLine());

         System.out.print("Enter load to be bought: ");
         load.setLoad(sc.nextDouble());

         System.out.println(load);     
         computeLoad(load);
         System.out.println(load);     
    }

    public static double computeLoad(Load load) {
        return load.setLoad(MAXIMIM_LOAD  - load.getLoad());
    }
}
```

---

The next improvement is to separate the responsibility, for this we create new  method

```
public class MyFirstProgram {

    private static double MAXIMUM_LOAD = 500.0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Load load = createLoad();

        System.out.println(load);     
        computeLoad(load);
        System.out.println(load);     

    }

    public static double computeLoad(Load load) {
        return load.setLoad(MAXIMIM_LOAD  - load.getLoad());
    }

    public static Load createLoad() {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); //We will read from the console. 

        System.out.print("Enter Cellphone Number: ");
        Load load = new Load(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Enter load to be bought: ");
        load.setLoad(sc.nextDouble());

            return load;
    }
}
```

---

But we should create a class for it to separate it from main static method.

```
public class LoadManager {

    public Load createNewLoad() {

        private static final double MAXIMUM_LOAD = 500.0;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); //We will read from the console. 

        System.out.print("Enter Cellphone Number: ");
        Load load = new Load(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Enter load to be bought: ");
        load.setLoad(sc.nextDouble());

        return load;
    }

    public computeLoad(Load load) {

        return load.setLoad(MAXIMIM_LOAD  - load.getLoad());
    }
}
```

---

Then we have:

```
 public class MyFirstProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LoadManger manager = new LoadManager();

        Load load = manager.createLoad();

        System.out.println(load);     

        manager.computeLoad(load);

        System.out.println(load);     
     }
}
```

---

One more thing to do is the safety as we use `System.in` we should close the resrouces.

```
public class LoadManager {

    private static final double MAXIMUM_LOAD = 500.0;

    public Load createNewLoad() {
        Scanner scanner;
        Load load ;
        try { 
            scanner = new Scanner(System.in); //We will read from the console. 

            System.out.print("Enter Cellphone Number: ");
            load = new Load(sc.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Enter load to be bought: ");
            load.setLoad(sc.nextDouble());

         } finally {
           if(scanner!=null)
               scanner.close();
         }
         return load;
     }

     public computeLoad(Load load) {

        return load.setLoad(MAXIMIM_LOAD  - load.getLoad());
    }
}
```

---